# VB.NET Structs and Nothing - problems

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-structures, structure

I'm having some headaches using Structures and functions that return Nothing in VB.NET.

Let me try to explain here with this code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Structure Test
        Dim field1 As String
    End Structure

    Private Function Foo() As Test
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim st As Test = Foo()
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the previous code, when I return Nothing as result of Foo function I'd expect that ***st*** is **Nothing**. But this is not what happens.

Then I found in MSDN documentation:

> Assigning Nothing to a variable sets it to the default value for its declared type. If that type contains variable members, they are all set to their default values.

So I discovered that when I assign **Nothing** to a structure, all its members are set to their default values, instead of the struct itself.

Also, I tried to make ***st*** a Nullable type by declaring:

```
    Dim st As Nullable(Of Test) = Foo()
```

but, still I can't check if ***st*** is Nothing by using:

```
    If st Is Nothing Then
```

or

```
    If st.Equals(Nothing) Then
```

So, questions:
1 - Is it possible to assign **Nothing** to the structure and not to its members?
2 - How can I check if a return struct value is **Nothing**?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869661/why-can-i-not-check-if-datetime-is-nothing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A structure is a value type, it cannot be Nothing.  The Nullable type can solve your problem, put a question mark after the type name to make it short and snappy.  Here's an example:

```
Module Module1

    Structure Test
        Dim field1 As String
    End Structure

    Private Function Foo() As Test?
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim st As Test? = Foo()
        Debug.Assert(st is Nothing)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: The ? is short-cut for `Nullable(Of Test)`.

Comment: @Hans Passant: No way, you cheat. My answer is so much better! :O)

Comment: Sorry @amiss, this is the kinda question where "just add a question mark" hands the OP the solution.  Surely your detailed answer will get many more upvotes than mine over the next 10 years.  Better check that IsEmpty theory though.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Can you go over to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169102/how-to-access-a-method-on-an-object-thats-passed-in-as-a-parameter-to-a-generic and make a comment regarding the assignment of a temp variable before calling Invoke and why it is a good idea. From a previous exchange of ours weeks ago, I make have made a technically incorrect comment that caused a flurry of other comments.

Comment: @AMissico: dtb is right, the copy of the reference was already made.  Same thing as copying it into *handler*.  Using the handler pattern is boilerplate until the egg doesn't get cooked the same way.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Ah, slipped my mind that handler was already assigned. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

The first two following methods are used frequently in the .NET Framework. The method you use will depend on your requirements. I will use Method #3 if the structure tested infrequently. For frequent testing, I will use Method #1 if Method #2 is not appropriate for "empty" testing. For instance, the `Point` structure defines an empty point as {x=0,y=0}, which I do not think is correct. Therefore, I would use the first method in my point structure implementation.

#### Method 1: Define `Empty` Test for Comparison Testing

Add shared `Test` to use for an empty-comparison.

```
Structure Test
    Public Shared Empty As Test = New Test
    Dim field1 As String 
End Structure
```

Test as:

```
If st = Test.Empty Then
```

#### Method 2: Define `IsEmpty` Property for Testing

Define an `IsEmpty` property based on the structure's internal state.

```
Structure Test 
    Public ReadOnly Property IsEmpty As Boolean
        Get
            Return Len(field1) = 0
        End Get
    End Property
    Dim field1 As String 
End Structure
```

Test as:

```
If st.IsEmpty Then
```

#### Method 3: Use Nullable(Of T)

Define as:

```
Dim st As Test? = Foo() 
'--or--
Dim st As Nullable(Of Test) = Foo()
```

Test as:

```
If st Is Nothing Then
'--or--
If st.HasValue = False Then
```

#### Note

I have not tested the above code and I do not have access to my code-library.

#### Inspiration

Take a look at Microsoft's `Point` and `Color` structures, using their published source code or using *.NET Reflector*.

Comment: Your first method requires the '=' operator overloading for the structure.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such concept as assigning "Nothing to the structure and not to its members".

It sounds very much like you should be looking at [nullable value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx) and [`Nullable(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) - if you need to be able to represent the absence of a "real" value for a value type, that's *precisely* the reason it was invented.

Consider `Byte` for example. A `Byte` value can have any of 256 values (0-255). If you assign it the value `Nothing`, that will actually make it 0. It can't make it "some value not in the range 0-255" as it's going to be stored *as a byte*. I regard it as somewhat unfortunate that VB *does* let you use `Nothing` here, actually... because philosophically a "missing" value and the value 0 are very different things indeed.

Anyway, nullable value types wrap "normal" value types and provide an extra Boolean value to say whether there's *really* a useful value present or not.