# Why can't I check if a 'DateTime' is 'Nothing'?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, null, nullable

In VB.NET, is there a way to set a `DateTime` variable to "not set"? And why is it possible to set a `DateTime` to `Nothing`, but *not* possible to check if it is `Nothing`? For example:

```
Dim d As DateTime = Nothing
Dim boolNotSet As Boolean = d Is Nothing
```

The second statement throws this error:

```
'Is' operator does not accept operands of type 'Date'. Operands must be reference or
nullable types.
```

Comment: In addition to John Gant's answer below, you can also check if the datetime variable = Nothing (Note the = instead of "is").

Comment: Thanks, using Dim boolNotSet As Boolean = d = Nothing seems like the most simple solution right now. Interesting with the Nullable casting never seen that before

Comment: @Chris - I think He is using VB

Comment: @Karthik Ratnam, yes he is but it amounts to the same thing and @Marc Gravell's answer gets all of the points across.

Comment: @Chris Haas: Not really, because of the Nothing keyword which has no equivalent in C#. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @NYSystemsAnalyst: according to [Nothing (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z%28v=vs.110%29), using `= Nothing` or `<> Nothing` is not good practice: "When checking whether a reference (or nullable value type) variable is **null**, do not use `= Nothing` or `<> Nothing`. Always use `Is Nothing` or `IsNot Nothing`."

Comment: @DavidRR I believe you mean `Not Is Nothing`

Comment: @Muleskinner: I believe that `IsNot Nothing` and `Not Is Nothing` are equivalent. From [IsNot Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c%28v=vs.110%29): "**IsNot** is the opposite of the **Is** operator. The advantage of **IsNot** is that you can avoid awkward syntax with **Not** and **Is**, which can be difficult to read."

Comment: @Muleskinner: Here is the list of the [keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409611%28v=vs.110%29) in the Visual Studio 2012 edition of Visual Basic. Not sure how long the `IsNot` keyword has been around.

Comment: @DavidRR Sorry my mistake, I see it was introduced in Visual Basic 2005

Comment: Be careful with using variable = nothing, this can lead to NullReferenceException

Answer (score 151, accepted):

This is one of the biggest sources of confusion with VB.Net, IMO.

`Nothing` in VB.Net is the equivalent of `default` in C#: the default value for the given type.

- For value types, this is essentially the equivalent of 'zero': `0` for `Integer`, `False` for `Boolean`, `DateTime.MinValue` for `DateTime`, ...
- For reference types, it is the `null` value (a reference that refers to, well, nothing).

The statement `d Is Nothing` is therefore equivalent to `d Is DateTime.MinValue`, which obviously does not compile.

Solutions: as others have said

- Either use `DateTime?` (i.e. `Nullable(Of DateTime)`). This is my preferred solution.
- Or use `d = DateTime.MinValue` or equivalently `d = Nothing`

In the context of the original code, you could use:

```
Dim d As DateTime? = Nothing
Dim boolNotSet As Boolean = Not d.HasValue
```

A more comprehensive explanation can be found on [Anthony D. Green's blog](https://anthonydgreen.net/2019/02/12/exhausting-list-of-differences-between-vb-net-c/#46)

Comment: Thanks for explaining. It is interesting to note that isNothing(d) does not work but d = Nothing does!

Answer (score 16):

DateTime is a value type, which is why it can't be null. You can check for it to be equal to `DateTime.MinValue`, or you can use `Nullable(Of DateTime)` instead.

VB sometimes "helpfully" makes you think it's doing something it's not. When it lets you set a Date to Nothing, it's really setting it to some other value, maybe MinValue.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414906/what-are-the-differences-between-value-types-and-reference-types-in-c) for an extensive discussion of value types vs. reference types.

Answer (score 5):

DateTime is a *value type*, which means it always has some value.

It's like an integer - it can be 0, or 1, or less than zero, but it can never be "nothing".

If you want a DateTime that can take the value Nothing, use a Nullable DateTime.

Answer (score 4):

Some examples on working with nullable `DateTime` values.

(See [Nullable Value Types (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245) for more.)

```vb
'
' An ordinary DateTime declaration. It is *not* nullable. Setting it to
' 'Nothing' actually results in a non-null value.
'
Dim d1 As DateTime = Nothing
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("d1 = [{0}]\n", d1))
' Output:  d1 = [1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM]

' Console.WriteLine(String.Format("d1 is Nothing? [{0}]\n", (d1 Is Nothing)))
'
'   Compilation error on above expression '(d1 Is Nothing)':
'
'      'Is' operator does not accept operands of type 'Date'.
'       Operands must be reference or nullable types.

'
' Three different but equivalent ways to declare a DateTime
' nullable:
'
Dim d2? As DateTime = Nothing
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("d2 = [{0}][{1}]\n", d2, (d2 Is Nothing)))
' Output:  d2 = [][True]

Dim d3 As DateTime? = Nothing
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("d3 = [{0}][{1}]\n", d3, (d3 Is Nothing)))
' Output:  d3 = [][True]

Dim d4 As Nullable(Of DateTime) = Nothing
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("d4 = [{0}][{1}]\n", d4, (d4 Is Nothing)))
' Output:  d4 = [][True]
```

Also, on how to check whether a variable is **null** (from [Nothing (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z%28v=vs.110%29)):

> When checking whether a reference (or nullable value type) variable is **null**, do not use `= Nothing` or `<> Nothing`. Always use `Is Nothing` or `IsNot Nothing`.

Answer (score 1):

In any programming language, be careful when using Nulls.  The example above shows another issue.  If you use a type of Nullable, that means that the variables instantiated from that type can hold the value System.DBNull.Value; not that it has changed the interpretation of setting the value to default using "= Nothing" or that the Object of the value can now support a null reference.  Just a warning... happy coding!

You could create a separate class containing a value type.  An object created from such a class would be a reference type, which could be assigned Nothing.  An example:

```
Public Class DateTimeNullable
Private _value As DateTime

'properties
Public Property Value() As DateTime
    Get
        Return _value
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DateTime)
        _value = value
    End Set
End Property

'constructors
Public Sub New()
    Value = DateTime.MinValue
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal dt As DateTime)
    Value = dt
End Sub

'overridables
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return Value.ToString()
End Function
```

End Class

'in Main():

```
        Dim dtn As DateTimeNullable = Nothing
    Dim strTest1 As String = "Falied"
    Dim strTest2 As String = "Failed"
    If dtn Is Nothing Then strTest1 = "Succeeded"

    dtn = New DateTimeNullable(DateTime.Now)
    If dtn Is Nothing Then strTest2 = "Succeeded"

    Console.WriteLine("test1: " & strTest1)
    Console.WriteLine("test2: " & strTest2)
    Console.WriteLine(".ToString() = " & dtn.ToString())
    Console.WriteLine(".Value.ToString() = " & dtn.Value.ToString())

    Console.ReadKey()

    ' Output:
    'test1:  Succeeded()
    'test2:  Failed()
    '.ToString() = 4/10/2012 11:28:10 AM
    '.Value.ToString() = 4/10/2012 11:28:10 AM
```

Then you could pick and choose overridables to make it do what you need.  Lot of work - but if you really need it, you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below just simple to check:

```
If startDate <> Nothing Then
your logic
End If
```

It will check that the startDate variable of DateTime datatype is null or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this like below :

```
if varDate = "#01/01/0001#" then
       '  blank date. do something.
else
       ' Date is not blank. Do some other thing
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

A way around this would be to use Object datatype instead:

```
Private _myDate As Object
Private Property MyDate As Date
    Get
        If IsNothing(_myDate) Then Return Nothing
        Return CDate(_myDate)
    End Get
    Set(value As Date)
        If date = Nothing Then
            _myDate = Nothing
            Return
        End If
        _myDate = value
     End Set
End Property
```

Then you can set the date to nothing like so:

```
MyDate = Nothing
Dim theDate As Date = MyDate
If theDate = Nothing Then
    'date is nothing
End If
```