# Convert Object Date to String in VB .net

Tags: vb.net, date, text

I need to convert item.MergedDate, which is a date, to a string.

Code as follows

```
If item.MergeDate.ToString() = "12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM" Then
    item.MergeDate = ""
End If
```

Obviously this is a terrible attempt, but

I have tried = Nothing 
and didnt work.

Thank You

Comment: its answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869661/why-can-i-not-check-if-datetime-is-nothing


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869661/why-can-i-not-check-if-datetime-is-nothing

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, and what is the end result that you want?

Comment: Well im trying to say, if the date is equal to 12/31/9999, for it to appear as a "TEXT" in the list view table.

Comment: binil, i dont see how that is the answer. 

MinValue I get a return of 01/01/0001 which is not "TEXT"

Answer (score 1):

Just an extension of SSS idea, but you could add another property to item, MergeDateAsString (Or overload it i suppose)

```
  Public Property Merge() As String
        Get
            Return _MergeDate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _MergeDate = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property MergeDateAsString
        Get
            Dim returnValue As String = String.Empty
            If _MergeDate <> Date.MinValue Then
                returnValue = _MergeDate.ToString
            End If
            Return returnValue
        End Get
    End Property
```

And then bind to the new property instead

Comment: I like the way you think spacemonkey. I will try that today.

Comment: I might have an issue because this object is used in other forms, but im sure that will be easy to get around.

Answer (score 0):

Change the data type of the Item.MergeDate property to a String

You can't store text in a Date variable.