# Error - 'Is' requires operands that have reference types, but this operand has the value type 'Integer'

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am new to VB.NET though I have some experiecne in C#. I am getting following error in VB.NET  code in .Net 2.0.

Error

> BC30020: 'Is' requires operands that have reference types, but this operand has the value type 'Integer'.

Following line is highlighted in red

```
 If selectedParameterNode Is Not Nothing Then
```

What is the reason for saying `XmlNode` is `integer`? How can we resolve it?

Note: I have referred [Why can't I check if a 'DateTime' is 'Nothing'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869661/why-can-i-not-check-if-datetime-is-nothing) for datetime. But this questions is for XMlNode

**VB.NET**

```
   Dim selectedParameterNode As XmlNode = objXml.SelectSingleNode("/ROOT/FPX[ParameterDesc = 'TEST33']/ParameterValue")
   Dim paramValue As String

   If selectedParameterNode Is Not Nothing Then
           paramValue = selectedParameterNode.InnerText
   End If
```

**XML**

```
<ROOT>

<FPX>
    <ParameterID>5</ParameterID>
    <ParameterDesc>Auto Cancel Case Labels When Change Destination</ParameterDesc>
    <ParameterType>BOOL</ParameterType>
    <MinValue>         &#x20;</MinValue>
    <MaxValue>         &#x20;</MaxValue>
    <ParameterValue>N</ParameterValue>
</FPX>

<FPX>
    <ParameterID>6</ParameterID>
    <ParameterDesc>Maximum Dozens Mfg WL</ParameterDesc>
    <ParameterType>NUMR</ParameterType>
    <MinValue>0         </MinValue>
    <MaxValue>10000     </MaxValue>
    <ParameterValue>999</ParameterValue>
</FPX>

<FPX>
    <ParameterID>7</ParameterID>
    <ParameterDesc>Maximum Dozens Assorted WL</ParameterDesc>
    <ParameterType>NUMR</ParameterType>
    <MinValue>0         </MinValue>
    <MaxValue>10000     </MaxValue>
    <ParameterValue>9999</ParameterValue>
</FPX>


</ROOT>
```

Comment: If selectedParameterNode **IsNot** Nothing Then or If Not selectedParameter Is Nothing

Comment: the error is that `Is Not` is the wrong syntax.  use `If selectedParameterNode IsNot Nothing Then`.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks. Can you please post it as an  answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that `Is Not` is the wrong syntax. use:

```
If selectedParameterNode IsNot Nothing Then...
```

It appears that splitting the word up it interprets `Not` as the part of an expression such as  `(Not Nothing)` which would be -1 (surprisingly, `(Not Nothing)` is legal).

Answer (score 1):

This is clarification to Plutonix's question, though likely unnecessary.

`selectedParameterNode Is Not Nothing` ends up being parsed essentially as `selectedParameter is (Not Nothing)`

`Not Nothing` is legal and resolves to `-1`.

Your check of `selectedParameterNode Is -1` caused your specific syntax error.

Possible solutions would be:

`If selectedParameterNode IsNot Nothing Then...` as Plutonix noted.

Or:

`If Not IsNothing(selectedParameterNode) Then...`

Or as long as your type supports the `<>` operator:

`If selectedParameterNode <> Nothing Then...`